# How to find the number of pairs of points that should contain a1..aN point in them. And should not contain b1,..bN points between them

Tags: math

How to find the number of pairs of points that should contain a1,a2,a3....aN (atleast one)point in them. And should not contain b1,b2,b3,..bN (atleast one) points between them.
e.g
1,2,3,4,5
a1=1,a2=4
b1=3
 ans should be (1,2)(1,1)(4,4)(4,5) total 5 points

Comment: What is a point? A pair of coordinates? What is a pair of points? Two coordinate pairs? Are the aN points? Are the aN values of coordinates? x? y? Same for bN?  In your example, what are 1,2,3,4,5? Please explain much more. Give more examples of input with desired output and explain why it is the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list `c = c1, c2, ..., ck`, a list `a = a1, a2, ..., ai` and a list `b = b1, b2, ..., bj`, find the number of pairs `(cx, cy)` of elements of `c` such that at least one of `cx` and/or `cy` is in `a` and neither `cx` nor `cy` is in `b`.

Consider the following sets of elements:

- Elements in `c`, but neither `a` nor `b`. Say we have `p` elements in this set.
- Elements in `c` and `a`, but not in `b`. Say we have `q` elements in this set.
- Elements in `c` and `b`, but not in `a`. Say we have `r` elements in this set.
- Elements in neither `c` nor `a`, but in `b`. Say we have `s` elements in this set.
- Elements in neither `c` nor `b`, but in `a`. Say we have `t` elements in this set.
- Elements not in `c`, but in `a` and `b`. Say we have `u` elements in this set.
- Elements not in any of `a`, `b` or `c`. Ignore these.
- Elements in all of `a`, `b` and `c`. Say we have `v` elements in this set.

We want to count:

- pairs with the left element in `a` and `c` but not `b`, and the right element in `a` and `c` but not `b`: `q` choices times (x) `q` choices gives `q^2` choices.
- pairs with the left element in `a` and `c` but not `b`, and the right element in `c` but neither `a` nor `b`: `q` choices times (x) `p` choices gives `qp` choices.
- pairs with the right element in `a` and `c` but not `b`, and the left element in `c` but neither `a` nor `b`: `q` choices times (x) `p` choices gives `qp` choices.

We don't want to count anything else as it either (1) doesn't have a member of `a` in it or (2) has a member of `b` in it or (3) contains things that aren't members of `c`. Our answer is therefore `q^2 + 2qp`.

All we need to do now is calculate `q` and `p`.

1. Sort `a`, `b` and `c` in ascending order.
2. Put markers at the first elements of the sorted lists `a`, `b` and `c`.
3. Advance the markers on lists `a` and `b` until they are at elements greater than or equal to the element at the marker on list `c`.
4. If the marker on list `c` is pointing to a different element than either of the elements pointed at by markers on lists `a` and `b`, we have found a new element contributing to the total value of `p`. Increment `p`.
5. If the marker on list `c` is at the same element as the marker on list `a`, we have found a new element contributing to the total value of `q`. Increment `q`.
6. Advance the marker on list `c` by one position, and then repeat this procedure from step 3 until the marker on list `c` visits all elements in the list. Then, return `q*q + 2*q+p`.